# Isabelle: verify tautological formula

Tags: isabelle, hol

I want to create a function F in Isabelle that is given a formula

```
       formula = pr int | neg formula | imp formula formula
```

and yields True if the formula is tautological and False otherwise.

For example:

```
F( φ ⇒ φ ) = True
F( φ ⇒ (ψ ⇒ φ) ) = True
F( ψ ⇒ φ ) = False
```

Can anyone help me? I find it really difficult to understand Isabelle's documentation and I cannot find such function (which I think that it should already exist).

Comment: Why should such a function already exist? You defined this datatype yourself, and there are many different kinds of logics. Surely you cannot expect the standard library to contain a huge collection of different logics deeply embedded into Isabelle.

Comment: Yeah I defined this datatype but this is basically saying that a formula is 
atomic (e.g. pr 1),
a negation of a formula (e.g. neg (pr 1) ) or 
an implication (e.g imp (pr 1) (pr 2) )

So I think Isabelle would have something that for a given formula, it would know if that formula is true for any assignment.

Comment: Well, as I said in my answer, you first need semantics for your formula (the `eval` function). As soon as you have that, writing down what it means for a formula to be tautological is quite easy.

Comment: I would like to add yet another reference to Manuel Eberl's comments and answer that you may find useful: https://www.isa-afp.org/browser_info/current/AFP/Propositional_Proof_Systems/document.pdf. The examples presented there are slightly more involved than your use case, but, hopefully, with some effort, you will be able to infer from these examples how Isabelle can be used for your application.

Answer (score 0):

In any case, if you want to talk about tautology of formulae (or about any semantic property of formulae), you first need to define semantics for your formulae, i.e. a function `eval :: formula ⇒ (int ⇒ bool) ⇒ bool` (assuming that the `pr` constructor represents free variables) that takes a formula and a variable assignment and returns whether the formula holds for that assignment or not.

You can define such a function by recursion over the formula using the `primrec` or `fun` command. There are many examples for those i the [‘Programming and Proving‘ tutorial](http://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2019/doc/prog-prove.pdf) on the Isabelle website.

Comment: I don't understand why the function is of the form eval :: formula ⇒ (int ⇒ bool) ⇒ bool . I mean, how would you define the base case for an atomic formula (pr 1). How would I know that an atomic formula (pr 1) is valid for a certain assignment?
And I would like to define eval for more than one integer...

Comment: That's why your assignments are of the type `int ⇒ bool`. They assign a value to every integer. You could make it more explicit and give the assignment a domain, but really that only makes it unnecessarily complicated. You typically just assign whatever you want (e.g. `False`) to all the variables you don't care about.

Comment: And for the base case `pr i`, defining `eval` is easy: You just look up `i` in the assignment.

Comment: This might be asking too much, but I don't see how would you define a tautology after having defined eval. You need to check that the formula holds for every possible assignment right?
I mean, ```taut( pr a) = False```,``` taut (neg b) = taut b ``` but what about ```taut (imp c d)```?

Comment: You just have to write down the definition of tautology formally: It evaluates to `True` for every assignment. (Hint: Isabelle/HOL has a universal quantifier `∀`) This won't be executable yet, of course (since there are infinitely many functions from `int` to `bool`), but I think it will be enough to prove or disprove tautology of specific formulae.

Comment: I think you should really do an Isabelle tutorial first, such as the one I linked in the article. Or, if you are not familiar with predicate logic, familiarise yourself with that before. But as an example for the use of `∀`: A natural number is prime if it is not 1 and all its divisors are either 1 or itself. Formally: `prime n ⟷ n ≠ 1 ∧ (∀d. d dvd n ⟶ d ∈ {1, n})`. Perhaps this illustrates how to use the universal quantifier. Now you just have to define ‘tautological’ as ‘evaluates to `True` for any assignment’.